Metadata-generation failed from email module using python 3.11
I'm trying to execute command pip3/pip install -win_requirements.txt and I observe that the email module is the problem.
The error is the following:
pip3 install email
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting email
  Using cached email-4.0.2.tar.gz (1.2 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [18 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 14, in <module>
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
          import setuptools.version
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/version.py", line 1, in <module>
          from ._importlib import metadata
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/_importlib.py", line 45, in <module>
          import importlib.metadata as metadata  # noqa: F401
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/usr/lib/python3.11/importlib/metadata/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
          from . import _adapters, _meta
        File "/usr/lib/python3.11/importlib/metadata/_adapters.py", line 3, in <module>
          import email.message
        File "/tmp/pip-install-lzxy69gd/email_f38b626eeefa44a098244f34710a1052/email/message.py", line 255
          if str(charset) <> charset.get_output_charset():
                          ^^
      SyntaxError: invalid syntax
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You are trying to install the package "email" which is part of the requirements file (should be win_requirements.txt as far as I can see).
The package comes with an install script, which has a syntax error:
"/tmp/pip-install-lzxy69gd/email_f38b626eeefa44a098244f34710a1052/email/message.py", line 255 if str(charset) <> charset.get_output_charset(): ^^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax [end of output]

They use "<>" instead of "!="; so the maintainer needs to fix it. What you can do is, installing an older version of the package by appending <VERSION to the package name. Pip tries to install version 4.0.2 of package email. So you might try "email<4.0.2"
Open the requirements file "win_requirements.txt" (or whatever it is called) and find the line "email" and replace it with "email<4.0.2". Then it should use the latest version before 4.0.2... if thats not working, you can specify any older version. Try e.g. <4.0.0 to install the latest 3.x.x revision.
EDIT:
It seems version 4.0.1 also has the issue. So try <4.0.0. If you run into an error about "setuptools" not being available, add it to your requirements file.
